# C# how to do a custom shell to replace explore.exe

Tags: c#

I would like to do a custom shell(.exe) that would replace explore.exe on startup, that verifies if mstsc.exe (with a .rdp configured) is running, to check if the remote desktop is running. If not then there would be a logoff activated.

My question is what type of application should I make? I was thinking of a Console App.
And how do I make sure it replaces explore.exe on startup ? I am new at this...

Comment: Have you searched a little ? What have you tried so far ? What **problem** have you encountered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to find what are the requirments to program a Windows Shell Remplacement. There a many good tutorials online to know where to start. It's not a small thing to build so I won't go into detail here an start coding it for you. For this part, do your homework and read about it you won't have any difficulties finding what you are looking for.

As for :

> And how do I make sure it replaces explore.exe on startup ?

You can set the `vReg_Sz` string value of

```
// Replace by your custom .exe shell
"Shell"="Explorer.exe"
```

to the full path of the program you wish to start by default.

This string is located at :

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

If you want to set it depending on which user is logged in, refer to `HCKU\..` instead of `HKML\..`:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```